# MarkerClusterer no error, but does nothing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Page loads, markers are set and shown, functions work, and so on...
Everything seems to be fine, but MarkerClusterer does not work.
What am i missing ?
Code optimization suggestions are welcomed as well :)

```js
<script>

var map;
var markers = [];

function loadjsonmarkerstomap()
 {
 $.getJSON("json.php", function(json1)
  {
  $.each(json1, function(key, data)
   {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
   var infocontent = "<div style='width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid grey;'>ID: " + data.id + "<br/>Type: " + data.type + "<br/>Weight: " + data.weight + '<br/><input type="submit" value="Show"/></div>';
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: data.title
    });
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: infocontent });
   marker.addListener('click', function()
    {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
   markers.push(marker);
   });
  });
 
 }

function clearLocations()
 {
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
  {
  markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers.length = 0;
 }

$('#clear').click(
 function()
  {
  clearLocations();
  }
 );
 
$('#load').click(
 function()
  {
  loadjsonmarkerstomap();
  }
 );


function initMap()
 {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  {
  center: {lat: 46.30499, lng: 25.292647}, //
  zoom: 8 //
  });

 loadjsonmarkerstomap(); //
 
 var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'images/m'});

 }
 


</script>
```

Comment: I believe it might not be working due to the markers being fetched asynchronously. Eg when you run your `loadjsonmarkerstomap()` and then immedialtely init your cluster. Your markers array is still empty. You have to make sure to init the cluster after the ajax call is successful

Comment: Do you mean to put the var markerCluster outside of the initMap() function ?

Comment: No, rather put the `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'images/m'});

 }` inside the callback of your ajax call. Eg directly after your `$.each(json1..` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes no difference :|
The m1.png, m2.png ... images are inside a folder named images, but there is no sub-folder m, does that have to do with anything ?

Comment: Nah that should be as intendend. Could you post a fiddle or something for further assistance? No console errors? How many markers do you load?

Comment: No Console errors, 42 loaded markers. Cant really post a fiddle, does it help you if I publish the results of the json.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124967/discussion-between-mee-and-erik-svedin).

Comment: @ErikSvedin you second hint solved my issue (Eg directly after your $.each(json1.. loop)
For some reason the first time ive inserted the code to the wrong place...
Thank you.
How to mark the comment as a good answer?

Comment: posted as answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it might not be working due to the markers being fetched asynchronously. Eg when you run your `loadjsonmarkerstomap()` and then immedialtely init your cluster your markers array is still empty.

You have to make sure to init the cluster after the ajax call is successful.

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'images/m'}); }
```

Should go inside the callback of your ajax call. Eg directly after your `$.each(json1.. loop`